# public static class or const

Tags: class, static, constants, public

Should I rather create a public static class or use internal constants?
I am working on a very large application and noticed the use of const string at numerous places.This is used to compare the users selection

```
const string Thatch = "Thatch";
const string BrickAndTimberFrame= "Brick And Timber Frame";
const string OtherRoof = "Other";
etc......
etc......
```

What I want to do is to rather create public static class in the Core Application (*see code below*). The reason for this is that I only have to change/add a value at one place only.

```
public static class RoofConstruction
{
  public static String Thatch{ get { return "Thatch"; } }
  public static String BrickAndTimberFrame { get { return "Brick And  Timber   Frame"; } }
  etc....
  etc....
}
```

The compare function will then look like this

```
 internal bool SlateTileOrConcreteRoof()
        {
            return RiskInformation.RoofConstruction.Value == RoofConstruction.Slate ||
                   RiskInformation.RoofConstruction == RoofConstruction.TileAndSlate ||
                   RiskInformation.RoofConstruction == RoofConstruction.Concrete;
        }
```

Please add any comments/improvements etc

Comment: Better use constants in a config file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Generally speaking, I think that “the defining characteristic of ‘a Good Class™’,” is that “it *does* the right thing, *nevermind(!) ‘how, exactly,”* it does it.”

When you export *constants* from the class, this suggests that an unknown-number of other sections of the application *(present and future ...)* will contain logic that tests against that string.

Therefore, the question that only you can really answer:   “do they really care about ‘the value of that string,’ or do they want ‘the answer to a yes-or-no question, which is answered in part based on the value of that string?’”   This might guide your decision about what is best to do. *(Mind you, I do not think that there is any sort of bright-line rule.   I have done it both ways...)*